# Как мне замерджить две ветки?

Tags: git, github

Я откатился к комиту при помощи git checkout <номер комита>. У меня создалась ветка * (HEAD detached at <номер комита>). На этой ветке я сделал пару изменений и закомитил это и теперь я хочу замерджить эти изменения в ветку dev. Для того  чтобы это сделать надо переклчится к ветке, а когда я это сделаю, у меня пропадет ветка  HEAD detached at <номер комита>) и все внесенные комиты, насколко я понимаю, пропадут.  Вообщем, как мне замерджить HEAD detached at <номер комита>) в dev?

Comment: Начать нужно с того, что у вас нет ветки. Detached head это не ветка. Впрочем никто не мешает запомнить хэш  коммита, переключится в dev и написать `git merge хэш`. Гит вполне справится.

Comment: На будущее: новая ветка делается командой `git branch имя-ветки`. В обшем почитайте документацию `git branch --help`

Comment: @AlexeyTen, это не сработало. Во-первых изменения, которые я закомитил не сохранились, а когда я замеджил, ничего не изменилось

Comment: Если закоммитил, то сохранились (как минимум пока сборщик мусора не сработал). Всегда можно создать из них ветку, главное знать хэш коммита

Comment: показывайте что и как вы делали

Comment: `git reflog` в студию

Answer (score 0):

До того как переключаться на ветку dev нужно было создать ветку на текущем коммите.

Так как это довольно частый use-case, у `git checkout` был добавлен параметр `-b <new_branch>`. Например: `git checkout -b tmp <номер комита>` создаст на указанном коммите ветку tmp и переключится на нее.